# Access c constant from Ada

Tags: c, ada

I have a header file with a type definition like this

```
#ifndef SETSIZE
   #define SETSIZE 32
#endif

typedef struct _set {
    unsigned  array[SETSIZE];
} set_t;
```

To use a corresponding C-function I need to have the set_t type available in Ada. The problem is that SETSIZE is a configurable parameter (with default value 32). If I understand it correctly I cannot access preprocessor defines from Ada.
Would it be possible to add a constant to the c-file and use this in Ada like this:

```
#ifndef SETSIZE
   #define SETSIZE 32
#endif

const size_t test = SETSIZE;
// Alternative
enum { test2 = SETSIZE };

--Ada--
-- import test somehow
type set_array is array (0 .. test) of aliased Interfaces.C.unsigned;
type set_t is record
  array_field : aliased set_array;
end record;
```

Or any other way to have this type correctly available in Ada without too much change in the original C-code

Comment: Implementation dependant features might help you. See for example https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gnat_ugn/Preprocessing.html

Comment: Nice, I didn't know about this feature. I will keep it in mind, but first will try the more clean way of Holt and Alex.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Why not simply:

```
SetSize: constant Interfaces.C.Size_T;
pragma Import(
    Convention    => C,
    Entity        => SetSize,
    External_Name => "set_size" 
);
```

And in your `C` file:

```
const size_t set_size = SETSIZE;
```

Tested with `gnatmake 4.8.1`:

```
// File: set_def.c
#include <stdlib.h>

#ifndef SETSIZE
   #define SETSIZE 32
#endif

const size_t set_size = SETSIZE ;

typedef struct _set {
    unsigned  array[SETSIZE];
} set_t;
```

Compiling `set_def.c`:

```
Z:\> gcc -c set_def.c
```

```
-- File: main.adb
with Interfaces.C, Ada.Text_IO, Ada.Integer_Text_IO ;

procedure Main is

    use type Interfaces.C.Size_T ; -- To have access to the - operator

    SetSize: constant Interfaces.C.Size_T;

    pragma Import (
        Convention    => C,
        Entity        => SetSize,
        External_Name => "set_size" 
    );

    -- Note that you should go to SetSize - 1
    type Set_Array is array(0 .. SetSize - 1) of aliased Interfaces.C.Unsigned;
    type Set_T is
      record
        Array_Field: aliased Set_Array;
      end record;

    MySet: Set_T := (Array_Field => (1, 2, 3, others => 0)); 

begin
   Ada.Integer_Text_IO.Put (Integer(SetSize), 0); Ada.Text_IO.New_Line;
   Ada.Integer_Text_IO.Put (MySet.Array_Field'Length, 0); Ada.Text_IO.New_Line;
   for I in MySet.Array_Field'range loop
       Ada.Integer_Text_IO.Put (Integer(MySet.Array_Field(I)), 0);
       Ada.Text_IO.Put(' ');
   end loop;
end Main;
```

Compiling `main.adb` and linking with `set_def.o`:

```
Z:\> gnatmake main.adb -largs set_def.o
Z:\> main.exe
32
32
1 2 3 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
```

Comment: That looks like what I was searching for.
Because SetSize is a constant it should be possible to use it to define the array. Seems great. I will try it when I am back at my desk.

Answer (score 4):

In a similar case what I did was to add a function to import from Ada:

```
size_t getsize(void) {
   return SETSIZE;
}
```

And in the Ada side:

```
function Getsize return Interfaces.C.size_t;
pragma Import(C, Getsize); -- From memory, this pragma is probably somewhat wrong
```

If you don't want to repeatedly call this function, for the (negligible I guess) overhead, you can have just after the function definition:

```
Setsize : constant Interfaces.C.size_t := Getsize;
-- Or convert to any more convenient type at this point.
```

I guess you could do the same with a variable too.

Comment: A nice collateral from Ada elaboration is that you can use the C constant in Ada for variable-sized things without having to rely on a predefined maximum size.