# Used C constant in Ada's modular type bound

Tags: ada, gnat

I have a similar problem to the one present in this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32079775/access-c-constant-from-ada).

I want to use a C constant in Ada as a range a of modular type.

Unfortunately I get an error:

```
linux-char_device.ads:52:27: non-static expression used for modular type bound
linux-char_device.ads:52:27: "MAJOR_NUM" is not a static constant (RM 4.9(5))
```

The C code is:

```
const unsigned major_num = 7;
```

The Ada code is:

```
MAJOR_NUM : constant Interfaces.C.unsigned;
pragma Import (
   Convention    => C,
   Entity        => MAJOR_NUM,
   External_Name => "major_num"
);

type Major_Type is mod MAJOR_NUM;
```

Comment: @RuudHelderman sorry, copied the wrong part of code. It does not work even with `const unsigned major = 7;`

Comment: Thanks for the edit. Seems like Ada is pretty picky when it comes to `mod`. Unless somebody comes with a brilliant idea, you may be forced to fall back on `range`; would that be an option?

Comment: Which features of modular types do you need for `Major_Type`?

Comment: @JacobSparreAndersen, @Ruud  Thank you. On a second thought, indeed I did not have to choose `mod`. I had the conception the this is what required for unsigned C type.

Answer (score 2):

Compile time constants are typically directly used in the resulting assembler code and can never be imported or exported from or to any language in gcc. That is, if your C code really contains

`const unsigned major_num = 7;`

you wont find major_num in the resulting object file, unless perhaps you use -O0. Try nm on any object file (for C or Ada, doesn't matter) to check.

You therefore cannot import a compile time constant in Ada. If you want to create an Ada binding for some C (or C++) functions you have to redeclare the C constant as an Ada constant:

`MAJOR_NUM : constant Interfaces.C.unsigned := 7;`

The easiest way is to use the gcc switch `-fdump-ada-spec` on a C header. See [Generating Ada Bindings for C and C++ headers](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc-7.2.0/gnat_ugn/Generating-Ada-Bindings-for-C-and-C_002b_002b-headers.html#Generating-Ada-Bindings-for-C-and-C_002b_002b-headers)

Comment: BTW, are you sure you want a modular type with wrap around semantics and a modulus of **7**? That doesn't exist in C in the first place.

Comment: @REE, Thank you. What you wrote is not what I experienced. Interfacing constant values works fine as long as they are not used do define a size of modular type. The number 7 is only an example (and I agree that it is a poor one). Eventually I abandoned the idea to use `mod`.